# CSS3 - shortest way fill a webpage with a variable number of rectangles of different sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an html5 template where the **page is filled with rectangles**.

If there is only one rectangle, it will take the whole screen. Other rectangles will then come up from the bottom, eating up the place of the first. 
**Each rectangle must be an html element** because I will put background-size:cover on it (so using the remaining container space to make up the first rectangle is not a viable solution). There are two layouts, one with two and the other with 3 columns.

***The exact behavior is available***  [here : JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/luqesa/1/edit?html,css,output)

It works perfectly fine but I think there are shorter and better ways to do that.

Any CSS expert around ? A JS solution is OK too but only if it is shorter. LESScss can be used too.

Maybe something with column-count?

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/4sy8nppo/)?

This solves only your "Portrait" section

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.box {
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:center;
}
.fullWidth {
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxNum = 12;
    var startNum = 1;

    function render() {
        if (startNum % 2 === 0) {
            $(".container").children(".box:nth-of-type(odd)").removeClass("fullWidth");
            $(".container").append("<div class='box'>" + startNum + "</div>");
        } else {
            $(".container").append("<div class='box fullWidth'>" + startNum + " </div>");
        }
        if (startNum < maxNum) {
            setTimeout(render, 1500);
        }
        startNum++;
    }
    render();
});
```

---

**EDIT** Added "Landscape" section

And like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/xdhmeag1/)?

This solves only your "Landscape" section

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
.box {
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 25%;
    width: 33.333%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:center;
}
.halfWidth {
    width:50%;
}
.fullWidth {
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxNum = 12;
    var startNum = 1;

    function render() {
        if (startNum % 3 === 0) {
            $(".container").children(".box").removeClass("halfWidth");
            $(".container").append("<div class='box'>" + startNum + "</div>");
        } else if ((startNum - 2) % 3 === 0) {
            $(".container").children(".box:nth-of-type(" + (startNum - 1) + ")").removeClass("fullWidth").addClass("halfWidth");
            $(".container").append("<div class='box halfWidth'>" + startNum + "</div>");
        } else {
            $(".container").append("<div class='box fullWidth'>" + startNum + " </div>");
        }
        if (startNum < maxNum) {
            setTimeout(render, 1500);
        }
        startNum++;
    }
    render();
});
```

Comment: well portrait is simple, it is done mainly by:nth-child(odd):last-child{width: 100%}. most of the is for landscape...

Comment: @Rayjax I have edited my answer and included landscape as well

Answer (score 0):

**Masonry** is an interesting framework that may help you with your situation...or possibly push your idea to a new level.

Take a look at the site and see if it can assist you in your endeavor:
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I know about masonry but this is not really appropriate as it is used for making blocks fit together. here the problem is what size each block should have depending on block number, then they simply fit with relative positioning

Comment: fair enough.. just sharing as it may have assisted.